# Evolution won't load any calendar whatsoever?

Tags: email, evolution, calendar, google-calendar, ms-exchange

Evolution won't load any calendar whatsoever. I tried Exchange (work), web based (for testing) and Google (private). There isn't even an error message. Nothing. I don't even have an idea where to start working on this problem... Colleagues of mine have the exact same settings, down to the last little bit, except for username and password obviously, and for them everything just works like a charm. I've also did like a weeks worth of googling by now, but no one on earth seems to have the this problem.

Calendars all state they are connected, with the little arrow symbol and saying online. But no actual events are loaded. Email works absolutly fine with the same accounts corresponding to the emails, both via Exchange and Google.

Comment: Which Ubuntu release is used?

Comment: @Pilot6 Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS